# Printing a calendar for a given year and month

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a program that will print out the month and year that the user inputs. What I have so far ends up with the year having 5 digits and inputting "2020 2" results in 28 days for the month of February.

The code I have so far in this assignment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int is_leapyear(int y)
{
  if ((y % 100 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
  int i, j, year, month;
  printf("Please enter the year and month:");
  scanf("%d", &year);
  scanf("%d", &month);
  int a[13] = { 0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
  int la[13] = { 0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
  int c = 1;
  int flag = 0;
  if (is_leapyear(year))
    flag = 1;
  for (i = 0; i<month; i++)
{
    if (flag == 1)
        c += la[i];
    else
        c += a[i];
}
int s = (year - 1) + ((year - 1) / 4) + ((year - 1) / 400) - ((year - 1) / 100) + c;
int week = s % 7;
printf("Calendar   " );
printf("%-d", year);
if (month < 10)
    printf("0");
printf(" %d\n", month);
printf("----------------------\n");
printf("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa \n");
printf("----------------------\n");

if (flag == 1) {
    for (j = 0; j < week; j++)
    {
        printf("   ");
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= la[month]; i++)
    {
        if ((week + i - 1) % 7 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (i < 10)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%d", i);
        printf(" ");
    }
}
else {
    for (j = 0; j < week; j++)
    {
        printf("   ");
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= a[month]; i++)
    {
        if ((week + i - 1) % 7 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (i < 10)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%d", i);
        printf(" ");
    }

}
printf("\n");
printf("---------------------\n");
}
```

The output:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It seems like I was too careless in reviewing my code, minor mistakes observed and problem solved!

Comment: I'd expect a `4` somewhere in `is_leapyear()`.

Comment: You can print the year and month with `printf("%4d %02d\n", year, month);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The century check on your isleapyear()

```
if ((y % 100 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0)
```

is flawed. It checked if the year is divisible by 100 *and* not divisible by 100, which is a logical impossibility. I think you actually mean

```
if ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0)
```

So check if the year is divisible by *4* and not divisible by 100.

As for the 20200, it's because your leading zero for the month is printed before the space is printed. Just change it to

```
printf("%-d", year);
printf(" "); //put space right away
if (month < 10)
    printf("0");
printf("%d\n", month); //no need to print space here
```

or even better as pointed out by @JonathanLeffler in the comment

```
printf(" %.2d\n", month);
```

It deals with space, the leading zero, and the new line in just one call, or just

```
printf("Calendar   %.4d %.2d\n", year, month);
```

to handle those three parts at once

Comment: You're right about the diagnosis of why the output is `20200 2`.  It would be better to use `printf(" %.2d\n", month);` or `printf(" %02d\n", month);` without the conditional in the program; both of those request 2 digits in the output, with a leading zero when necessary.  And there's no need for the extra calls to `printf()`.  Indeed, that line could all be printed trivially with one call to `printf()` —— `printf("Calendar   %.4d %.2d\n", year, month);`.

Answer (score 1):

OP's `is_leapyear(int y)` fails with various multiples of 4.

Instead:

```
// Alternative for Gregorian calendar
int is_leapyear(int y) {
  if (y % 4 == 0) {
    if (y % 100 == 0) {  // A century year?
      return (y % 400 == 0);
    } 
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Deeper: [Leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).